# Function returning void with liveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm using Room to handle my local database, and LiveData to handle the DAOs.
So I'm using LiveData as thread handler for my transactions.
The question is how can I do insert and updates with LiveData? Or generally **how can void functions return LiveData** in the Room?

```
@Query("select * from table")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<T>>
```

```
@Insert
fun insert(T data): LiveData<?> // What should be the generic, since it's void?
```

In RxJava we have something like this:

```
@Insert
fun insert(T data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is how can I do insert and updates with LiveData? Or generally how can void functions return LiveData in the Room?

You can't use LiveData object itself to insert or update data in your database (db). LiveData is a wrapper around the object loaded from db which can be observed.

In order to perform insert/update operations you need to pass the object annotated with `@Entity`annotation to your `DAO` method parameter. You can do it either by calling `LiveData#getValue()`, or observe the LiveData in Activity, or Fragment and update a local variable via the observer and pass said variable.

Comment: So in order to insert something I need to use a thread handler like `new Thread().start()` ? And liveData is useless here?

Comment: Yes, you can use `new Thread().start()` for these operations, as well as any other way of performing operation off the main thread like `AsyncTask`, though `new Thread().start()` is the easiest way of doing it.